# Multiple comparison operator output wrong results powershell

Tags: powershell, comparison-operators

Here is my script:

```
#set the root search path
$rootPath = "c:\test\path\"

#get a list of all directories and subdirectories in the root path
$shares = Get-ChildItem -Path $rootPath -Directory

#create empty array to store custom properties later
$obj = @()

#for every folder you find.....
foreach ($share in $shares) {

    #finds all security principals for each share on fileserver that has permissions explicitly assigned   
    $notInherited = Get-Acl -Path $share.FullName |  select -ExpandProperty Access | Where-Object {$_.IsInherited -eq $false} 

    #for every security principal that has explicit permissions assigned....
    foreach ($member in $notInherited) {

        #extract the identity of the resource from the IdentityReference field and convert it to a string object
        [string]$identity = $member.IdentityReference

        #test to see if the extracted resource contains a \ anywhere in the name to ensure we're looking for domain objects
        if ($identity -like '*\*') {

        #retrieve the SAM of the resource by splitting the string object at the \ and returning the 1 field
        $samAccountName = $identity.Split('\')[1]

            #filter out all domain related groups like domain admins, domain users, domain controllers, domain computers
            if ($samAccountName -notlike 'Domain*' -or $samAccountName -notlike 'Administrators') {

                #return AD object info for the resource using it's SAM
                $ADObject = Get-ADObject -Filter ('SamAccountName -eq "{0}"' -f $SamAccountName)

                #test to ensure we're only retrieving groups and not users who are explicitly assigned
                if ($ADObject.ObjectClass -eq 'group') {

                    #create a PS object and append it's properties to the empty array created earlier
                    #assign custom fields to the object (FolderName maps to the share name and GroupName maps to name of group that has access to the share)
                    $obj += [pscustomobject] @{
                    'GroupName' = $ADObject.Name
                    'FolderName' = $share.Name
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#output the contents of the object to the console
Write-Output $obj | ft -AutoSize | out-file C:\Scripts\test02.txt
```

I'm wondering why this line produces wrong results:

```
if ($samAccountName -notlike 'Domain*' -or $samAccountName -notlike 'Administrators')
```

I would expect the output to not include any folders where the 'Administrators' or any groups that start with 'Domain' are explicitly added. If i remove the 2nd half to test so that it only checks for 'Domain*', the output is correct. I need to filter out the Administrators group too. What am i missing?

Comment: try -and instead of -or `if ($samAccountName -notlike 'Domain*' -and $samAccountName -notlike 'Administrators')`

Comment: lol fail on my part. I could've sworn I did -and the first time and it didnt work....anyhow, that solved my problem. Thanks.!

Answer (score 1):

Your request:

```
if ($samAccountName -notlike 'Domain*' -or $samAccountName notlike 'Administrators')
```

literally translates to "Not like X" or "Not like Y"

What I think your looking for is:

```
if (!($samAccountName -like 'Domain*' -or $samAccountName -like 'Administrators'))
```

{ write-host "Yes" }

This way, if $samAccountName is like 'Domain*' -or $samAccountName ``-like 'Administrators', it returns TRUE, and then the ! converts that to a false.

So, if either condition is met, the result is false, and the block of code is NOT run.  so, if a user is a domain* or the user is an Administrator, it will NOT output "Yes"..